# Facebook api uploading event £ character wont display

Tags: events, facebook-graph-api, utf-8, upload, special-characters

I`ve looked over the facebook api document and can find no reference to character set, I assume their using utf-8, our normal charset is iso-8859-1.

We're uploading events to a Facebook page, any time the document contains a pound sign (£) its miss-converted appearing as �

There appears to be no method of setting a charset, and using `&pound;` or `&#163;` or `&#xA3;` just results in those showing as is.

Is there any way of setting the charset or other method to send such character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I`ve found a answer.

A possible solution was to change the file encoding to utf-8 (which does work), but that would be very unsatisfactory, as it means your mixing charsets on the site and that page would have trouble reading some characters from your SQL dBase and would write to same in a different charset to the rest.

However, a UTF-8 £ sign appears as `Â£` in iso-8859-1, so on upload replace any £ signs with `Â£` and Facebook will show them correctly as £.

If someone has a better explanation or a more general solution please share.